# XPages:sending mail using Java agents

Tags: java, xpages, javaagents

I am trying to send using Jave agent with body field that could either be a type of RichtextItem, Mimeentity or Text, when ever i run i get the error

> lotus.domino.local.Item incompatible with lotus.domino.RichTextItem

is there any way i could make the Item compatible with each other before passing it to the Stream?

```
RichTextItem bodyrt =  memo.createRichTextItem("Body"); 
RichTextItem body =  (RichTextItem) document.getFirstItem("Body");
if(body != null){
    bodyrt.appendRTItem(body);

}
stream = session.createStream();
stream.writeText(bodyrt.getText());
```

Answer (score 2):

RichtextItem extends NotesItem. So you can use Item any time and do a instanceof check before you try the cast. Or just use the item. I found working with a mime approach (sample classes from OpenNTF.org) less headache